# what is use of Tuple.getStringByField("ABC") in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am not able to understand the use of the Tuple.getStringByField("ABC") in Apache Storm.

The following is the code:

```
   Public Void execute(Tuple input){ 
       try{
          if (input.getSourceStreamId.equals("signals"))
            {
                str=input.getStringByField("action")

                if ("refresh".equals(str))
                  {....}
             }
             }...
```

Here what is **input.getStringByField("action")** is doing exactly..

Thank you.

Comment: you have two options input.getStringByField("action") or input.getStringValue(0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In storm, both spout and bolt emit tuple. But the question is what are contained in each tuple. Each spout and bolt can use the below method to define the tuple schema.

```
  @Override
  public void declareOutputFields(
      OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer)
  {
    // tell storm the schema of the output tuple
    // tuple consists of columns called 'mycolumn1' and 'mycolumn2'
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("mycolumn1", "mycolumn2"));
  }
```

The subsequent bolt then can use `getStringByField("mycolumn1")` to retrieve the value based on column name.

Comment: Assuming you are also emitting *string* values for 'mycolumn1' and 'mycolumn2'

Answer (score 1):

`getStringByField()` is like `getString()`, except it looks up the field by it's field name instead of position.