# incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, collections, apache-storm, bigdata

I'm trying to get the value of the tuple by the String but when i'm doing it getting an error saying

```
 incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

this is how I'm Trying.

```
 `  public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
  String field = tuple.getValueByField("name");

        for(String user:field.split(","))}`
```

I tried like this by casting the string

```
String field = (String) tuple.getValueByField("name");
```

Is this a correct way to get the value of the tuple by the field name?

Comment: Which `Tuple` class are you using?

Comment: yes it is correct, if return type is string. Are you getting any error on (String) tuple.getValueByField("name");  ?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
tuple.getStringByField("name");
```

`getStringByField` is used to retrieve the value, based on column name.

[Apache storm Documentation](https://storm.apache.org/apidocs/backtype/storm/tuple/Tuple.html#getStringByField(java.lang.String))

[what is use of Tuple.getStringByField(“ABC”) in Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28946576/4290096)

Answer (score 1):

try using getStringByField instead

if you want to use getValueByField then you will need to check
if (obj instanceof String)
then cast it

Answer (score 1):

yes it is correct, if return type is string.

```
String field = (String) tuple.getValueByField("name");
```

See example for reference

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple&method=getValueByField

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
String field = String.valueOf(tuple.getValueByField("name"));
```

instead of

```
String field = (String) tuple.getValueByField("name");
```